# Можно ли сверстать такую фигуру?

Tags: html, css, css3

Можно ли сверстать такую фигуру на CSS, чтобы не вставлять рисунком?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container__figure,
.container__figure:before,
.container__figure:after,
.figure,
.figure:before,
.figure:after {
  display: block;
  width: 8.5em;
  height: 8.5em;
  background: green;
}

.container__figure:before,
.container__figure:after,
.figure:before,
.figure:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.container__figure {
  position: relative;
  top: 2.5em;
  left: 2.5em;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.container__figure:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.container__figure:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

.figure {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 7.5em;
  padding: .5em 0em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.figure:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.figure:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(75deg);
}

.figure span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: gold;
}

.figure span.price {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__figure">
  <div class="figure">
    <span>Новая</span>
    <span class="price">$99.99</span>
    <span>цена</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, поворотами такое можно сделать. Но, наверное, есть и другие варианты, да и в виде svg это будет куда лучше.

```css
.wrapper {
   margin: 30px;
}
.x {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.x:nth-child(2){ transform: rotate(15deg); }
.x:nth-child(3){ transform: rotate(30deg); }
.x:nth-child(4){ transform: rotate(45deg); }
.x:nth-child(5){ transform: rotate(60deg); }
.x:nth-child(6){ transform: rotate(75deg); }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="x"></div>
  <div class="x"></div>
  <div class="x"></div>
  <div class="x"></div>
  <div class="x"></div>
  <div class="x"></div>
</div>
```